# Google Cloud Functions: What's a good development workflow?

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using JavaScript features that are not yet supported by GCP's node version ([Node v6.14.0](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/)) such as async/await so I am thinking of using Webpack and something to reload my code every time I save. The problem with using Webpack is that there will have to be an output file, so do I just not gitignore it or is there a way to have GCP build my code?

I am also using [Google Cloud Function Emulator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator), but it doesn't seem to support live reloading - is there a way around it? Just use an express server and [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) in development?

Comment: [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/overview#what_are_google_cloud_functions) are intended to provide single-purpose operations usually attached to events emitted by your infrastructure. They're not really designed with extensive asynchronous operations in mind. You might find a more suitable solution using App Engine Flexible and a [custom environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#nodejs_version) that allows you to use a Node version that supports async/await. Version 7.6 was the first to officially support async / await

Comment: async/await can be transpiled to es5 though. I am trying to write a cloud function that writes to a db which I think is a pretty common use case for cloud functions.

Comment: You might find this useful. It's a [video on using async/await with Typescript in Cloud functions and some corresponding code examples](https://gist.github.com/CodingDoug/814a75ff55d5a3f951f8a7df3979636a). It's geared towards Firebase but it may be useful for your purposes as well as Cloud Functions works in the same way on GCP.

Comment: Did you ever get nodemon working with local emulator? It is tiresome having to stop and start the server after changes.

Comment: @dazza5000 I ended up just making my own node server (which obviously works with nodemon) and putting my function in there. When I got it working, I tested it with the cloud function emulator and hosted it.